# How to make an animation that goes up and down in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make an animation of a clown go slightly up and down to simulate jumping up and down.

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
def first_bozo(gameWindow):
    gameWindow.blit(bozo, (50, clown_move))


    while True:
        clock.tick(80)
        clown_move = clown_move - 1

        gameWindow.fill(LIGHTBLUE)
        first_text()
        gameWindow.blit(big_top, (250, 250))
        pygame.draw.rect(gameWindow, DARKBLUE, [70, 170, 360, 70])
        button_text()
        pygame.display.update()

        if clown_move == 305:
            clown_move = clown_move + 1

            gameWindow.fill(LIGHTBLUE)
            first_text()
            gameWindow.blit(big_top, (250, 250))
            pygame.draw.rect(gameWindow, DARKBLUE, [70, 170, 360, 70])
            button_text()
            pygame.display.update()

        if clown_move == 300:
            clown_move = clown_move - 1
            gameWindow.fill(LIGHTBLUE)
            first_text()
            gameWindow.blit(big_top, (250, 250))
            pygame.draw.rect(gameWindow, DARKBLUE, [70, 170, 360, 70])
            button_text()
            pygame.display.update()

def intro_screen(): ### opening screen
    gameWindow.fill(LIGHTBLUE)
    first_text()
    gameWindow.blit(big_top, (250, 250))
    first_bozo(300)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameWindow, DARKBLUE, [70, 170, 360, 70]) 
    button_text()
```

it says

```
  gameWindow.blit(bozo, (50, clown_move))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'blit'
```

how do i fix?

Comment: The `first_bozo` function takes a `gameWindow`, but in `intro_screen` you give it an `int` (`300`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to post the code that's calling `first_bozo()` for me to really be sure, but it sounds like you're passing it an int rather than a game window object.

EDIT: As I said, in the code you pasted, you are passing an int to first_bozo. This int, 300, becomes the value of the `gameWindow` argument to first_bozo, and of course as the error says, 300 does not have a `blit` function. Replace `300` with `gameWindow` and you should at least be able to make some progress.

Comment: Hi, i added the code. I am very confused as to why its mistaking it for something else

Comment: Now my screen loads! But no clown on my screen. I will figure that out. Thank you!!